# Prove with generalized Cauchy integral formula

Tags: complex-analysis

Show with the help of Generalized Cauchy Integral Formula, if $ f(z)$ is entire with $|f^{(n)}|\le N$ for all z, then $f(z)$ is a polynomial of degree at most n.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First think about Liouville's theorem: a bounded entire function is constant. Since $f$ is entire, so is $f^{(n)}$, and since $f^{(n)}$ is bounded it is constant. Thus $f^{(k)} = 0$ for all $k \ge n+1$, making $f$ a polynomial whose degree is at most $n$.

Second, if you want to prove this directly from the integral formula, look up the proof of Liouville's theorem. It will be straightforward to modify.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use Liouville's Theorem here?  Since $f$ is entire, so is $f^{(n)}$, and with the additional assumption that $f^{(n)}$ is bounded, it is constant by Liouville's -- what sort of functions have constant n-th derivatives?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I can't use the theorem here directly.

Comment: OK, so as Umberto suggests, adapt the proof of Liouville's to fit your purpose -- it's also basically what Maryam's answer says, it just shows more of the adapted proof.  The proof of Liouville's is a pretty direct use of the CIF.